# "datetime-local" control: Which events are triggered when the control closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I *track/catch* with JQuery when a `datetime-local` control has been closed for what ever reasons:

1. Datetime has been selected.
2. `Cancel` button clicked.
3. `Reset` button clicked.

This is the very simple HTML tag:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="myDateTime">
```

Comment: from the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local): you have only change and input events

Comment: @gaetanoM Exactly what I read but I was hoping there are some other methods.

Comment: I think no way. It is up to the browser......

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will trigger for close but below code will must work when do you changed/select the date.
Below code work for me.

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="myDateTime" id="myDateTime">

$("#myDateTime").bind("input", function (evt) {
                    console.log(evt, evt.target.value);
                });
```